# Datepicker Angular Material Outline Form, Place Title in Top

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7

I am trying to create an Angular Material Datepicker without Ideal Outline version like this.
How would someone create this?

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Effective Start Date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker">
        <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>calendar_today</mat-icon>
    </mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Ideal goal is this:**

[image]

Currently with appearance = "outline" it is giving the view. Date is in the box rather than in outline title.

[image]

Please ignore the scale sizing issues, when pasting images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
<mat-label>Outline form field</mat-label>
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" >
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker">
    <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>calendar_today</mat-icon>
</mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

Use mat label instead of placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-form-field class="col-md-3 mt-1" appearance="outline">
 <mat-label>Start date</mat-label>
 <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" disabled="false" [value]="StartDate" 
  (dateInput)=pickDateStart($event)>
 <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker">
  <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>event</mat-icon>
 </mat-datepicker-toggle>
 <mat-datepicker #picker [startAt]="" disabled="false">
 </mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```